# How can I use/load the downloaded Hugging Face models from snapshot_download?

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, huggingface-hub

I have downloaded the model from [Hugging Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugging_Face) using `snapshot_download`, e.g.,

```
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download

snapshot_download(repo_id="facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M", cache_dir="./")
```

And when I list the directory, I see:

```
ls ./models--facebook--nllb-200-distilled-600M/snapshots/bf317ec0a4a31fc9fa3da2ce08e86d3b6e4b18f1/
```

Output:

```
config.json@             README.md@                tokenizer_config.json@
generation_config.json@  sentencepiece.bpe.model@  tokenizer.json@
pytorch_model.bin@       special_tokens_map.json@
```

I can load the model locally, but I'll have to guess the snapshot hash, e.g.,

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(
    "./models--facebook--nllb-200-distilled-600M/snapshots/bf317ec0a4a31fc9fa3da2ce08e86d3b6e4b18f1/",
    local_files_only=True
)
```

That works, but how do I load the Hugging Face model without guessing the hash?

Comment: Can we simply do `git clone` rather than downloading the snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a better directory management by making a separate directory instead of using a local one for the snapshot download, e.g.

```
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download

snapshot_download(
    repo_id="facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M", 
    cache_dir="./huggingface_mirror"
)
```

Then you can load the model using the `cache_dir` keyword argument:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(
    "facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M",  
    cache_dir="huggingface_mirror",
    local_files_only=True
)
```